# Restore access to Recovery Volume after update to Big Sur

Tags: recovery, big-sur

After updating macOS from Catalina to Big Sur, I cannot boot into the recovery volume by pressing <kbd>Cmd+R</kbd> during boot anymore. Rather than booting from the recovery volume when holding <kbd>Cmd+R</kbd>, I see a spinning globe indicating that some system image is fetched from the internet.

Is there a way to restore access to the local recovery volume for Big Sur without wiping the disk and doing a complete re-install of the operating system?

#### diskutil list

I think, the recovery volume is still present. When running `diskutil list`, I stil see the `APFS Volume Recovery`. Do I need to re-add some boot flags to make it work again?

```
▶ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.9 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.9 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.9 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD - Daten   1.8 TB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 292.5 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                613.9 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD           15.1 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 15.1 GB    disk1s5s1
```

I've tried to run Disk Utility's **First Aid** on `disk1`. However, this has not fixed the issue. First-Aid Results: https://gist.github.com/fiedl/dca819f185d3577e53fac8e553a29c0f

#### Things I've tried

- I've tried to use a [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) stick: When I boot from rEFIt, I can see the Recovery Volume. But when I try to boot from it, I get the error: "The firmware refused to boot from the selected volume."
- I've tried to [reset the nvram](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) with <kbd>Command+Option+P+R</kbd> during startup, which does not resolve the issue.
- I've used a bootable macOS install usb stick and run Disk Utility's First Aid from there, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried holding down the option key instead? Once booted to the Mac Startup Manager, then pressing Cmd+R.

Comment: Yes, actually I have tried that, but this also brings me to the spinning globe.

Comment: Do you have a recovery volume? Your question refers to a recovery partition, but neither Catalina or Big Sur use a recovery  partition. Also, does your Mac have a T2 chip?

Comment: I may have confused "recovery partition" with "recovery volume". I've posted my `diskutil list` volume layout. This is an older Mac without T2 chip.

Comment: Your disk layout looks right for BS, with a Recovery Volume.  But if it won't boot to Recovery Mode (but goes to Internet Recovery Mode) maybe your Recovery Volume is not right.  I would let it do Internet Recovery and reinstall BS.  But BEFORE doing anything, make sure you have a good backup.